# Log-normal distribution in R

Tags: r

Can someone explain to me how to fit the following grouped frequency data to log-normal distribution in R?

```
df<-data.frame(age=c(18,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,31,32,35,37,40,44,49,50,55,60,63,67,80),
               count=c(100,110,120,125,125,110,100,90,80,70,60,45,30,15,12,10,8,3,2,1,1))
```

`fitdist(df$count,"lnorm")` works, because it uses only one variable. But I need to use both age and count variables.

Is there a way to use two variables with fitdist?

```
fitdist(df$age,df$count,"lnorm")
```

This doesn't work. What I want to get are two parameters in lognormal distribution.

Something like this.

```
meandlog: 3.6098, sdlog: 0.40081
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in base R using `nls` to fit a non-linear least squares to a lognormal distribution. Since we are working on counts data rather than density, we also need to model a constant so that the density gets multiplied to the same range as counts:

```r
mod <- nls(count ~ c * dlnorm(age, meandlog, sdlog), 
           data = df, 
           algorithm = 'port',
           start = list(c = 1, meandlog = 1, sdlog = 1), 
           lower = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01))
```

Assuming we can ignore the constant, this means we can get the mean and sd from the model like so:

```r
coef(mod)[-1]
#>  meandlog     sdlog 
#> 3.2422408 0.3407284
```

To show that this is correct, we can plot the actual counts against those predicted by our model:

```r
plot(df$age, df$count, type = 'h')
lines(10:80, predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(age = 10:80)))
```

[image]

And, since we have the values we need to emulate the distribution of counts, we can just plot them directly using `dlnorm`

```r
plot(df$age, df$count, type = 'h')
lines(10:80, 2529 * dlnorm(10:80, 3.242, 0.3407), col = 'red')
text(x = 60, y = 80, 
     label = substitute(count %prop% dlnorm(age, 3.242, 0.3407)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Better to not hard-code the coefficients in the last calls to `lines` and `text`? For `label=` you can use `bquote` and `round`. A bit uglier, but also a bit more principled and generalizable...

Comment: @MikaelJagan sure - I almost did that, but decided that since I was attempting to show that the actual numbers that the model spits out are correct rather than producing an accurate high-quality plot I would keep it simple. In reality I would use ggplot here anyway, but as I say, it's just a quick proof-of-concept.